# Ruby: How to reference a variable defined outside of a module

Tags: ruby, module, scope

How do I pass `processor_pool` to the method inside the module?

```
class Dummy

  def initialize
    processor_pool = Concurrent::FixedThreadPool.new(10)

    @threadpool = Module.new do
      extend Concurrent::Promises::FactoryMethods
      def self.default_executor
        return processor_pool  # this cannot find the processor_pool variable
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I get the same error even if I make it an instance variable like `@processor_pool`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this (I simplified your class a bit to get rid of dependencies for the sake of example, but its structure is the same):

```rb
class Dummy
  attr_reader :threadpool
  
  def initialize
    processor_pool = "It works"

    @threadpool = Module.new do
      define_method :default_executor do
        return processor_pool
      end
      module_function :default_executor
    end
  end
end

Dummy.new.threadpool.default_executor # => "It works"
```

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the question.  The problem is that the module itself can't find the reference to the `processor_pool` variable (the line with the comment on it).

Comment: Method definition in Ruby is a so called "scope gate" (one of). That's why in your variant module doesn't "see" `processor_pool` and in my one variant it does - in your variant variable gets out of scope and in my variant it is captured by the block(s) and stays available.